# code push not loading cordova.js file

Tags: reactjs, code-push

Hi I'm finding that after running: 
`code-push release app-android build/www/ 0.11.1 --deploymentName Staging`

I get the following error:
````file:///data/data/bundle.app.name.id/files/codepush/deploy/versions/8sds645e6325b1bfcac0181c396d377a21946f764526cd7cd0480c6c2a47d9a/www/cordova.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND```

cordova.js seems to be requested from the codepush path, how do I fix this? do I need to set cordova.js path to `../../../../../www/cordova.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodePush Cordova plugin expects you to release the platform-specific www folder to the server, which would include the cordova.js file in it. In your example, if you simply change the folder you are releasing to "platforms/android/assets/www", you should be good to go. Also, make sure to run "cordova prepare android" before doing the release so that the www folder has the latest changes.

You can check out the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/blob/master/README.md#releasing-updates) for more details on what the CLI/plugin expects when releasing.

Let me know how that works out!